# What can be said about $x^TAx$ is terms of $\|x\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

What can be said about $x^TAx$ is terms of $\|x\|$?

I know that from C-S inequailty, $|x^TAx| \leq \|x\| \|Ax\|$, can I go further?

Comment: You could use $||A x || \leq ||A|| ||x||$ where $||A||$ is the operator norm of $A$ (which is the largest singular value of $A$ for the 2-norm).  If $A$ was symmetric, you could use $\frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$ is maximized  over non-zero $x$  to be the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: I guess the product can take any value if you choose $A$ accordingly

Comment: @Batman - so the following is true? $|x^TAx| \leq \sigma _{max}(A)\|x\|^2$

Comment: Yes. Its just a combination of what you had with the first statement I made.

Comment: @Batman. Thanks! You've helped me a lot!